# How to embed an image to a cover image by selecting random pixels in cover image?

Tags: python, steganography

```
def embedding(hideImagePath,coverImagePath):
    img1 = cv2.imread(coverImagePath, 0)
    img2 = cv2.imread(hideImagePath, 0)
    for i in range (img2.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img2.shape[1]):
                #convert pixel to binary 
                pixels_cover = format(img1[i][j], '08b')
                pixels_hide = format(img2[i][j], '08b')
                #replace the last 2 LSB from cover image with 2 MSB from hide image
                stegoImage = pixels_cover[:6] + pixels_hide[:2]
                img1[i][j] = int(stegoImage, 2)
    cv2.imwrite('StegoImage.png', img1)
```

Above is the code that I done so far. It hide pixels in cover image sequentially but I need it to hide the image to the cover image by selecting random pixels from the cover image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually you want to generate all the pixel coordinates and shuffle them in a deterministic way, so that the extraction knows where to look.

```
import itertools as it
import random

def permute_indices(shape, password):
    indices = list(it.product(*map(range, shape)))
    random.seed(password)
    random.shuffle(indices)
    return iter(indices)
```

For example

```
>>> idx = permute_indices((600, 800), 'hunter2')
>>> for _ in range(5):
    print(next(idx))

    
(411, 359)
(379, 680)
(110, 612)
(246, 388)
(232, 605)
```

Adjustments to your code

```
def embedding(hideImagePath, coverImagePath, password):
    img1 = cv2.imread(coverImagePath, 0)
    img2 = cv2.imread(hideImagePath, 0)
    indices = permute_indices(img1.shape, password)
    for i in range (img2.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img2.shape[1]):
                x, y = next(indices)
                #convert pixel to binary
                pixels_cover = format(img1[x][y], '08b')
                pixels_hide = format(img2[i][j], '08b')
                #replace the last 2 LSB from cover image with 2 MSB from hide image
                stegoImage = pixels_cover[:6] + pixels_hide[:2]
                img1[x][y] = int(stegoImage, 2)
    cv2.imwrite('StegoImage.png', img1)
```