# Embed every bit of every pixel of the secret image into the cover image

Tags: python, opencv, steganography

First, I read the cover image as greyscale image.

```
coverImage = cv2.imread(coverImagePath, 0)
```

Then I pass the cover image to another function to create another smaller image and that smaller image is my secret image.

```
def makeSecretImage(coverImage):
    copyImage = coverImage.copy()
    secretImage = cv2.resize(copyImage, (100,100))
    return secretImage
```

After that I pass the two images to my embedding function to embed the secret image into the cover image. My intention is to embed every bit of every pixel of the secret image to the **LSB** of the cover image and the LSB of the cover image is selected randomly. The final output of this function is a stego image which will looks exactly same with the cover image as it only change the LSB of the pixel.

```
def embedding(coverImage,secretImage, password):
    indices = permute_indices(coverImage.shape, password)
    for i in range (secretImage.shape[0]):
        for j in range(secretImage.shape[1]):
            x,y = next(indices)
            #convert pixel to binary 
            pixels_cover = format(coverImage[x][y], '08b')
            pixels_hide = format(secretImage[i][j], '08b')
            binary = list(pixels_hide)
            #error : keep overwriting the last bit
            for dataIndex in range(0,8):
                stegoImage = pixels_cover[:7] + binary[dataIndex]
                dataIndex += 1
        coverImage[x][y] = int(stegoImage, 2)
    cv2.imwrite('StegoImage.png', coverImage)
```

Then the stego image is read and pass to the extracting function. Here I'm getting the last bit of the selected pixel and form back to pixel. Then those pixel values placed back to the black image. But I'm getting error here as it read extra pixels from the stego image.

```
def extracting(stgimg,secretImage, password):
    Swidth, Sheight = stgimg.shape
    Ewidth, Eheight = secretImage.shape
    newPixel = []
    pixelList = []
    # create 2 blank images 
    OriImg = np.zeros((Swidth, Sheight, 1), np.uint8) 
    ExtractedImg = np.zeros((Ewidth, Eheight, 1), np.uint8)
    indices = permute_indices(stgimg.shape, password)
    for x in range(Swidth):
        for y in range(Sheight):
            a, b = next(indices)
            stegopixel = format(stgimg[a][b], '08b')
            bitValue = stegopixel[-1]
            newPixel.append(bitValue)
    for i in range(0, len(newPixel),8):
        pixelBit = ''.join(newPixel[i:i+8])
        pixelByte = int(pixelBit, 2)
        pixelList.append(pixelByte)
    img = np.array(pixelList, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(secretImage.shape)
    cv2.imwrite('ExtractedImage.png', ExtractedImg)
```

Comment: Numpy uses height as first index, so you want `np.zeros((Eheight, Ewidth...`

Comment: @Reti43 Sorry, I'm getting this error "cannot reshape array of size 13650 into shape (100,100)". Is this because inside the for loop it read the unwanted pixel ?

Comment: Your embedding and extracting functions do two wildly different things. In fact `embedding` seems to have an error. Is your intention to hide every bit of every pixel of `secretImage` in `coverImage` and then extract that back again?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide every bit of every pixel of the secret image into the cover image and extract back the secret image.

Comment: @Reti43 I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have an error in `embedding`

```
for dataIndex in range(0,8):
    stegoImage = pixels_cover[:7] + binary[dataIndex]
    dataIndex += 1
```

You hide 8 bits in the LSB of the same pixel, effectively overwriting them and keeping only the last one. You're supposed to hide each bit in a different pixel and so **you need at least 8 times more pixels in your cover image than what your secret has**. With that in mind

```
def embedding(coverImage, secretImage, password):
    stegoImage = coverImage.copy()
    indices = permute_indices(coverImage.shape, password)
    for pixel in secretImage.flatten():
        # no need for string "bit manipulation", straight up bitwise operations
        for shift in range(7, -1, -1):
            x, y = next(indices)
            bit = (pixel >> shift) & 0x01
            stegoImage[x,y] = (coverImage[x,y] & 0xfe) | bit
    return stegoImage
```

And then

```
def extracting(stegoImage, password):
    indices = permute_indices(stegoImage.shape, password)
    pixels = []
    for _ in range(secretImage.size):
        pixel = 0
        for _ in range(8):
            x, y = next(indices)
            bit = stegoImage[x,y] & 0x01
            pixel = (pixel << 1) | bit
        pixels.append(pixel)
    pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(secretImage.shape)
    return pixels
```

---

**Edit**: I've modified the above functions to return the image arrays instead of saving them, so I can directly test it with the original input. This also assumes that `permute_indices` is still the same as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877440/2243104).

```
password = 'password'
coverImage = cv2.imread('original.png', 0)
secretImage = makeSecretImage(coverImage)
stegoImage = embedding(coverImage, secretImage, password)
extractedImage = extracting(stegoImage, password)

diff = coverImage.astype(int) - stegoImage
print(diff.min(), diff.max())                 # Differences should be in the [-1, 1] range
print(np.all(secretImage == extractedImage))  # True
```

Comment: Hi, I already try it out but the image I get seem like not same with the original image. I wish to show here but it cant paste photo here.

Comment: @psps I've updated the answer to show you how I got the intended output. I don't know how you got the stego image shown in your question with my code, because the modifications are extremely visual. In either case, it works as intended. Note that I'm not saving the images here, just using the image arrays directly to save a few lines of code.

Comment: I already tested the code and the stego image and the extracted image seems fine. The result I get is [-1,1] and True. Thank you!!  BTW, how you do the bit shifting ? I can't really understand that.

Comment: @psps You can read on AND, OR and LOGICAL SHIFT on the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). But in short, say you have the number 235, which is 11101011 in binary. To get its bits from left to right, first shift to the right by 7 and keep only the LSB, then shift to the right by 6 and only keep the LSB, etc.  When you're building it back up you shift it one to the left and add the new bit. For example, say you have the temporary number 14, which is 1110 in binary, and the next bit is 1. Shift it to make it 11100 and then add the new bit. 11101 = 29 in decimal.